# git rebase internal error - exceeds size limit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have 2 local branches called master and working. I have a couple of commits on working and one commit on master. I wanted to bring the changes from master to working.

I currently have the 'working' branch checked out. I tried rebasing with 'master'. It showed one conflict file. I resolved the conflict and added the file to git. Now if I continue Rebase, i get the following error:

[image]

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this from the BASH emulator?

Comment: Yes, I tried the following: $ git rebase -i master
error: could not apply 5407dd4... form 8 changes - intermediate

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 5407dd4... form 8 changes - intermediate

Comment: I'd check what you're trying to squash (`5407dd4`) - I think if you compare that with the commit you're trying to squash it into, you may see what the issue is.

Comment: the exceed file was coming because I had an installer exe. I just ignored the file and it resolved. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the exceed file was coming because I had an installer exe. I just ignored the file and it resolved.